# Smoothing Process Over an Image Using STD

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, std

```
import cv2
```

import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from PIL import Image
from skimage import io
import glob
from skimage import io, img_as_float

img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\hoday\Desktop\GRAPE_IMG\GrapeBox.jpg", 1)
img = np.float32(img)

blue_img, green_img, red_img = cv2.split(img) #split the image into 3 channels - BGR

channels = [blue_img, green_img, red_img]
std_channels = []

for channel in channels:

```
lst = []           

img_row = (channel.shape)[0]
img_col = (channel.shape)[1]

for row in range(1, img_row-1): #for 5X5 1--->2
    for col in range(1, img_col-1): #for 5X5 1--->2
        mask = channel[row-1:row+2, col-1:col+2] #for 5X5 ---> mask = channel[row-2:row+3, col-2:col+3]
        lst.append(mask.std())
        
std_channel = np.array(lst)        
std_channel = std_channel.reshape(img_row-2, img_col-2) #for 5X5 2--->4
std_channels.append(std_channel)
```

img_merged = cv2.merge(std_channels)
cv2.imwrite(r"C:\Users\hoday\Desktop\GRAPE_IMG\normalStd.png", img_merged)

Hi,
I'm trying to go through the pixels of an image and take out a new image consisting of std
Just like what was done in the next video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZoaEDbivmOE&t=80s

I split the image into 3 channels and tried to update a new array for each channel but when I try to run the code I get stuck. For example Instead of print the value 5.58 for img[0:3, 0:3].std() like it is supposed to do, the value that it's print is 1.28 - now that is the value of std for one channel but i want the merge one with all the three ...

Probably i dont merge the channels in the right way but i have no idea how else i can do it.

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you mean by "stuck".

Comment: i get an error - File "std_img.py", line 26, in <module>
    std_blue = np.append(std_blue, np.append(lst), axis = 0)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 4, in append
TypeError: _append_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'

Comment: But I tried the same function on a small array and it worked. So i think maybe the picture is too big to deal with in this way but i dont know what else i can do

Comment: What is STD please?

Comment: Its a short for standard deviation. There is a function in python for this (like the way i did in my code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You can get it down to under 1ms with **Numba**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import math

@nb.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True, fastmath=True)
def numbaStd(im):
    # Allocate space for result
    res = np.zeros_like(im)
    h, w, c = im.shape
    for row in nb.prange(1,h-1):
        for col in range(1,w-1):
            for band in range(c):
                x0 = im[row-1,col-1,band]
                x1 = im[row-1,col  ,band]
                x2 = im[row-1,col+1,band]
                x3 = im[row  ,col-1,band]
                x4 = im[row  ,col  ,band]
                x5 = im[row  ,col+1,band]
                x6 = im[row+1,col-1,band]
                x7 = im[row+1,col  ,band]
                x8 = im[row+1,col+1,band]
                mu = (x0 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8) / 9
                S  = (x0 - mu)**2
                S += (x1 - mu)**2
                S += (x2 - mu)**2
                S += (x3 - mu)**2
                S += (x4 - mu)**2
                S += (x5 - mu)**2
                S += (x6 - mu)**2
                S += (x7 - mu)**2
                S += (x8 - mu)**2
                res[row,col,band] = math.sqrt(S/9)
    return res

# Open image and make into Numpy array
im  = cv2.imread('grapes.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Call Numba standard deviation
res = numbaStd(im)

# Optional block to contrast stretch result image
res[...,0] = 255.0*res[...,0]/res[...,0].max()
res[...,1] = 255.0*res[...,1]/res[...,1].max()
res[...,2] = 255.0*res[...,2]/res[...,2].max()

# Save result
cv2.imwrite("result.png", res)

# IPython timing
#%timeit numbaStd(im)


In [19]: %timeit numbaStd(im)
864 µs ± 20.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

[image]

---

**Original Answer**

You can more simply use the **SciPy** [generic_filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter.html?highlight=generic#scipy.ndimage.generic_filter) to pass a 3x3 window over the image like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter

# Stddev filter
def stddev(P):
    """
    We receive P[0]..P[8] with the pixels in the 3x3 surrounding window.
    """
    return np.std(P)

# Open image and make into Numpy array
im = Image.open('paddington.png')
im = np.array(im)

# Run 3x3 stddev filter on one band/channel at a time
im[...,0] = generic_filter(im[...,0], stddev, (3, 3))
im[...,1] = generic_filter(im[...,1], stddev, (3, 3))
im[...,2] = generic_filter(im[...,2], stddev, (3, 3))

# Save result
Image.fromarray(im).save('result.png')
```

That turns this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

---

By the way, you can do the same thing, without writing any code, in Terminal with **ImageMagick** like this:

```
magick paddington.png -separate -statistic standarddeviation 3x3 -combine result.png
```

Comment: thank you !!! in the end I succeed with the loop way also, but in both of the ways it's taking a lot of time until it show the result image. is it suppose to take so much time ?

Comment: It is quite a significant amount of processing. If I get some time, I may try splitting the image into its component channels and seeing if that improves the caching, or maybe `Numba` or maybe multiprocessing.

Comment: just one more question - why in somw images I get everything black when it's suppose to show me  the differences in the  colors ?

Comment: Kindly share an image that doesn't work if you would like me to have a look. Thank you.

Comment: I have added 3 lines of code just before the final "image save" to contrast stretch the result and added in the processed result. I made the result integer so you could see it as an image because few formats support float values. You can change it to float quite easily by changing the line that allocates the results to `res = np.zeros_like(im).astype(np.float)`.

Comment: Is there a way to print the picture with the for loop I posted in the begining ? Imanage to do it with small images but when I run it on more "big" ones it's stuck

Comment: And why didnt you use the function std() in the numbda function ?

Comment: You are welcome to adapt my code to use the `std()` function if you prefer - I just did it that way to give the compiler a chance of organising things the way it saw fit. No-one (least of all me) says my approach is perfect, it is just an idea to get you started.

Comment: Printing out thousands of pixels in a loop is not really sensible. If I wanted to do that, I  would write the output file as a TIFF (which supports floats) then use **ImageMagick** to dump any values with `magick result.tif txt:` or `magick result.tif -crop 6x5+1+2 txt:` to print 5 rows and 6 columns starting at row 2 column 1.